# Regex: How to exclude one group within another group?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a computer generated text that looks like as follows (I've modified the white space to make it more pleasant on the eyes).

```
<li class="activitybit forum_post">
    <div class="avatar">
            <img src="image.php?s=64ca7b4cc0fa2850f6c763105eee901b&amp;u=37080&amp;dateline=1396817868&amp;type=thumb" alt="killathi's Avatar" />
    </div>
    <div class="content hasavatar">
        <div class="datetime">
             <span class="date">Today,&nbsp;<span class="time">07:14 PM</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
                <a href="member.php?37080-killathi&amp;s=64ca7b4cc0fa2850f6c763105eee901b">killathi</a> replied to a thread  <a href="showthread.php?1016907-doodles!-Maybe-I-won-t-have-lines-in-it-this-time!!!-MUAHAHHAHAHAAHAH&amp;s=64ca7b4cc0fa2850f6c763105eee901b">doodles! Maybe I won't have lines in it this time!!! MUAHAHHAHAHAAHAH</a> in <a href="forumdisplay.php?208-Fan-Creations&amp;s=64ca7b4cc0fa2850f6c763105eee901b">Fan Creations</a>
        </div>
        <div class="excerpt">I'll hold this one here for now I guess, not really sure where to go with it lol</div>     
        <div class="fulllink"><a href="showthread.php?1016907-doodles!-Maybe-I-won-t-have-lines-in-it-this-time!!!-MUAHAHHAHAHAAHAH&amp;s=64ca7b4cc0fa2850f6c763105eee901b&amp;p=9844450#post9844450">see more</a></div>

    </div>
    <div class="views">77 replies | 3407 view(s)</div>
</li>
```

I've used the regex : `(?:<div class=\"title\">)((?:[\s\S]*?))(?:</div>)`
and I've extracted the following in the first non-ignored group:

```
<a href="member.php?37080-killathi&amp;s=64ca7b4cc0fa2850f6c763105eee901b">killathi</a> replied to a thread  <a href="showthread.php?1016907-doodles!-Maybe-I-won-t-have-lines-in-it-this-time!!!-MUAHAHHAHAHAAHAH&amp;s=64ca7b4cc0fa2850f6c763105eee901b">doodles! Maybe I won't have lines in it this time!!! MUAHAHHAHAHAAHAH</a> in <a href="forumdisplay.php?208-Fan-Creations&amp;s=64ca7b4cc0fa2850f6c763105eee901b">Fan Creations</a>
```

However, I'm wondering if its possible to (and if so how do you) exclude everything within triangular brackets using regex.

I know that I need to do something in `((?:[\s\S]*?))` but I'm not really sure how to do it.
(It is safe to assume all text will come in this format).

Comment: I just love to refer people to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1049308

Comment: You do realize that post has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: It has everything to do with this question. You're trying to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: No. I'm trying to MATCH some particular text and I was wondering if i could exclude a group of data existing within a different group. There is a difference between matching and parsing.

Comment: Can you show your expected result in this case? You want everything that is not a tag?

Comment: @fnightangel the string I'm looking to get is "killathi replied to a thread doodles! Maybe I won't have lines in it this time!!! MUAHAHHAHAHAAHAH  in Fan Creations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace everything inside triangular brackets just use this regex:

```
<[^>]*>
```

like so:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "<[^>]*>", "");
```

[here's the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Most of the way there but you'd probably want that to be non-greedy. See my answer.

Comment: @StevePettifer non greedy isn't needed, I search for anything other than a closing bracket 0 or more times followed by a closing bracket, try it out if you're curious.

Comment: Yes, good point, I managed to mis-read that somehow which is amazing when you consider how short it is!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use this library: [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)

You can extract your text as simple as this:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtml);

var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='title']");
string result = node.InnerText;
```

Comment: I have a feeling that would give you everything that wasn't directly part of the `<div>` tag including all the `<a>` tags it contains. You'd then need to parse that further (but I may be wrong as it's been a while since I used it so I may stand corrected).

Comment: Actually no, `node.InnerHtml` will do.

Comment: Fair enough - like I said it's been a while. I do indeed stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking a RegEx Replace might do it, but it is notoriously hard to manipulate html in the general case with regexes. Here is [a fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/NszMFn) which demonstrates the use of `(<.+?>)`. It works on your example but I make no guarantees!